# Reference global component class in local JSS style?

Tags: material-ui, jss

I'm using material-ui with react, and what I want to do style a standard material-ui component when it appears within a local class. Conceptually, something like:

```
const styles = {
  localClass: {
    '& MuiGrid-item': {
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
  }
}
```

I see in JSS how to reference local classes with the `$` notation, and how to override/augment material-ui styling with `createTheme`, but I have been unable to find anything on how to accomplish this use case.

Comment: So far, I've been able to find what feel like workarounds on a case-by-case basis, but I'm also becoming more aware that there's just a different fundamental style to JSS as well. My take is that it's not so much "CSS done in JS" (which was the model I had in mind), but more "an alternative style framework that compiles into CSS". As such, there are some things that are better about each approach, and other places where they're just different.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I know this has been a while, but I was wondering if you found any way to do that by now.

Comment: Not exactly. The styling model is just different, and this highly desirable feature of CSS+HTML just doesn't seem available. You can solve some of the same problems, but you have to come at it a different way. I've posted an answer; let me know if it addresses your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After continuing to work on this, it seems that the answer is "things work different", so the kind of styling which would be elegant in CSS+HTML can be awkward or downright impossible in CSS+JS. It does seem to me that the CSS+JS model has thrown the baby out with the bathwater in some cases, but that's how it is at the moment.

Still, in many cases where you want to use modify component styling based on context (=~ the presence of parent components or enclosing style classes) can be reasonably accomplished by other means, but it depends a bit on the specific use case.

In cases where the goal is to change the behavior of a specific component, just wrap the component in a new class directly. E.g.:

```
const style = { root: { backgroundColor: 'red' } } 

StyledWidget = withStyle(style, 'StyledWidget')(
  () => <Widget classes={{ root: classes.root }} />
```

Where you want to make something re-usable (at the code level at least), create a styling widget that accepts a rendering component, or create a higher order component that injects style classes. E.g.:

```
<WidgetStyler component={TextInput} ... />
<WidgetStyler component={Buttton} />
```

or

```
StyledWidget = withWidgetStyling(TextInput)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 ways to customize MUI styles https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/

Comment: I'm aware, that doesn't really answer the question though. Unless you're saying there's no support for this use case, or the use case fits in one of those four ways in a non-obvious way. Also, the clear intent of the question is how to apply general CSS context selection to this situation, and, again, the documentation does not seem to address it.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the right answer but I was looking for an answer for a pretty similar question and I hope mine can spark some ideas. In my case I have the following hierarchy of components

```
    <ListItem
      className={classes.navLink}
      component={Link}
      activeClassName="active"
      to={`/graphiql`}
      button
    >
      <ListItemText
        classes={{ primary: "navLink-text" }}
        primary="GraphiQL"
      />
    </ListItem>
```

This is the representation of a navigation link inside a responsive navigation drawer called `NavDrawer`. With this setup, the `ListItem` - the generated `<a />` - receives the className `active` when the `Link` is active.

The `NavDrawer` can receive a navItems prop containing similar navigation links. So in order to target and styles these `active` nav links globally, I added the following to theNavDrawerwithStyles`:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  "@global": {
    ".active .navLink-text": {
      color: theme.palette.primary.main,
      fontWeight: 500,
      letterSpacing: "0.1em"
    }
  },
  root: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  // other rules here
}
```

With this, no matter where the nav links came from, they get the corresponding active styles when rendered inside the `NavDrawer`.

The code for the `NavDrawer` is basically a copy paste of the responsive navigation drawer from the Material UI docs.